# implements service class the app is crash when phone switch off and on

Tags: android

I am new in android  my question is that when i start the recording through power button with  help of service class,code is proper work when i switch off my phone and open again, my app crash.Please help me..

**My service class is:--**

```
public class PowerButtonService extends Service implements MediaListner {

BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP3 = ".mp3";
static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_3GP = ".3gp";
static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP4 = ".mp4";
private Handler mHandler;
SharedPreferences prefs;
private Runnable mRunnable;
String file_exts[] = { AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP3,
        AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP4, AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_3GP };
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "AudioRecorder";
private int count;
Sessions sessions;
int recordCount = 0;
private Editor mEditor;
private MediaRecorder recorder = null;
private int currentFormat = 0;
private int output_formats[] = { MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4,
        MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP };

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    mReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    sessions = new Sessions(PowerButtonService.this);
    sessions.setServiceInstance(this);
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mEditor = prefs.edit();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mEditor.putBoolean("PowerButtonServiceStart", false);
    mEditor.commit();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Recording from power button is stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    Log.i("onDestroy Reciever", "Called");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    final Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) this
            .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    if (!prefs.getBoolean("check", false)) {
        recordCount = recordCount + 1;
        if (recordCount == 3) {
            if (prefs.getBoolean("RecordingOnInsideApp", false)) {
                vibe.vibrate(1000);
                recordCount = 0;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Recording is already running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            } else {
                mEditor.putBoolean("powerbutton", true);
                mEditor.commit();
                if (null == recorder && !(Sessions.getRecordOnActivity())) {
                    recordCount = 0;
                    System.out.println("recoding on");
                    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]);
                    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                    recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
                    recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
                    recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);
                    try {
                        recorder.prepare();
                        recorder.start();
                        vibe.vibrate(700);
                        Notifyuser();
                        mHandler = new Handler();
                        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (null != recorder) {
                                    mEditor.putBoolean("powerbutton", false);
                                    mEditor.putString("PowerButtonTime",
                                            "00:00:00");
                                    count = 0;
                                    mTimer.cancel();
                                    mEditor.commit();
                                    Sessions.setRecordOnService(false);
                                    recordCount = 0;
                                    recorder.stop();
                                    recorder.reset();
                                    recorder.release();
                                    System.out.println("hello helloo");
                                    Sessions.StopPowerButtonRecording();
                                    vibe.vibrate(3000);
                                    recorder = null;
                                }
                                Log.e("Ho rha hai", "goodndnd");
                            }
                        };
                        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 900000);
                        Sessions.setRecordOnService(true);
                        startTimer(mEditor);
                        Sessions.startPowerButtonServiceTime();
                        vibe.vibrate(1000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    if ((Sessions.getRecordOnActivity())) {
                        Sessions.getServiceActivity();
                        vibe.vibrate(5000);
                    }
                    if (null != recorder) {
                        Sessions.setRecordOnService(false);
                        recordCount = 0;
                        recorder.stop();
                        recorder.reset();
                        recorder.release();
                        Sessions.stopServiceTimer();
                        vibe.vibrate(500);
                        recorder = null;
                        mEditor.putBoolean("powerbutton", false);
                        mEditor.putString("PowerButtonTime", "00:00:00");
                        count = 0;
                        mTimer.cancel();
                        mEditor.commit();
                        Sessions.setRecordOnService(false);
                        recordCount = 0;
                        recorder.stop();
                        recorder.reset();
                        recorder.release();
                        System.out.println("hello helloo");
                        Sessions.StopPowerButtonRecording();
                        vibe.vibrate(3000);
                        recorder = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("time over...");
                recordCount = 0;
            }
        }, 3000);
    } else {
        vibe.vibrate(1000);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Recording from Widget is already Running",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private String getFilename() {
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MMM_yy_HH_mm_ss");
    String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(System
            .currentTimeMillis()));
    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "Rec_" + dateString + file_exts[currentFormat]);
}

private MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener errorListener = new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
    }
};

private MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener infoListener = new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
    }
};
private Timer mTimer;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onMediaStopListner() {
    if (null != recorder) {
        if (mHandler != null) {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
        }
        mEditor.putBoolean("powerbutton", false);
        mEditor.putString("PowerButtonTime", "00:00:00");
        count = 0;
        if (mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
        }
        mEditor.commit();
        recordCount = 0;
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();
        Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) this
                .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibe.vibrate(1000);
        System.out.println("onMediaStopListner in Power button service");
        System.out.println("powerbutton "
                + prefs.getBoolean("powerbutton", false));
        System.out.println("PowerButtonTime "
                + prefs.getString("PowerButtonTime", ""));
        recorder = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onMediaStartListner() {

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void Notifyuser() {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
            "Recording Start", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
            | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Recording Find", ".....",
            contentIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(10, notification);

}

public void startTimer(final Editor editor) {
    try {
        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                String timer = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                        count / 3600, (count % 3600) / 60, (count % 60));
                count++;
                editor.putString("PowerButtonTime", timer);
                editor.commit();
                System.out.println("This is only For  Testing" + timer);
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    if (prefs.getBoolean("powerbutton", false)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Recording has been saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        final Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) this
                .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        if (null != recorder) {
            mEditor.putBoolean("powerbutton", false);
            mEditor.putString("PowerButtonTime", "00:00:00");
            count = 0;
            mTimer.cancel();
            mEditor.commit();
            Sessions.setRecordOnService(false);
            recordCount = 0;
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.reset();
            recorder.release();
            System.out.println("hello helloo");
            Sessions.StopPowerButtonRecording();
            String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(ns);
            nMgr.cancel(10);
            vibe.vibrate(3000);
            recorder = null;
        }
    }
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}
```

Comment: add your exception log

Comment: You forgot to post error log

Comment: how can i get the error log because i am doing  mobile swith off when i On the error log does not show anythings.